# Fold all except current cursor and keep cursor position

Tags: vimrc

I would like to map a key so I can quick close all folds but keep unfolded on current cursor and keep cursor's position too.
Through `:h fold` I can use `zMzv` but it can't keep cursor's position.

Comment: Oddly enough, I tried `zMzv` today and it kept the correct cursor position... curious.

Comment: I should be more clear about this, I _mapped_ to a key so that it will contain `<CR>` at the end and reset cursor to next line.

Comment: Why do you need the `<CR>` though? I.e., why doesn’t for example `nnoremap <leader>zo zMzv` do the trick?

Comment: Sorry about the question, you're right. But screen will blink because close and open fold task - the output. mark seems sovled it, but Idk why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a mark at the beginning of your mapping and then jump there at the end. For example:

```
nnoremap <leader>zv :normal mazMzv`a<CR>
```

---

**Postscript:** *This was posted when I was merely an apprentice Vim Ninja rather than the MVN (Master Vim Ninja) you see before you today. Of course, in the <ahem>* normal *course of things one would be wasteful to create such an nmap when `` nno <leader>zv mazMzv`a `` is equivalent. Funny thing, though...OP says the less enlightened version was the only one to solve his problem. Personally I can't reproduce even the cursor moving part so I just take them at their word and this answer lives on; a signpost aside the road on which I journeyed to top of the mountain.*  B Layer - 6/14/2020 **;)**

Comment: I am curious if am I missing something?  If I press `zx` , `zv` , `zMzv`, etc.. the folds change but the cursor does not move.  So I don't understand why the mark is necessary.

Comment: If you map `zx` to a key: `nnoremap <space>zx :zx<CR>` for i.e, ` zx` will change cursor's position.